# WPF 15 extra pixels in Window display

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, designer

I come from a WinForms background, so WPF is foreign to me. I am experimenting with it and trying to make a simple Hello World! application, except that the application displays different at runtime than how it is in the designer.

What I mean by that is I have a 'Hello!', and in the designer the location of the button is 12, 12, and and the Window is sized so that is the right/bottom edge of the button is 12, 12 pixels from the right/bottom edges of the window (so there is uniform 12 pixels around the button). When I run the application the button is still 12, 12 pixels from the top & left edges, but is 27, 27 pixels from the right/bottom edges of the Window. I have verified that the button dimensions are correct (I took a screenshot and measured the button in Adobe Photoshop and verified that the button width & height in the XAML code was the same as what was displaying on the screen). The Window is what is growing bigger.

I also verified it was not the canvas getting bigger by explicitly setting the width & height, changing the background color, and setting horizontal/vertical alignment to left/top. So when I ran it again, the canvas stayed the same size, but the Window still had an extra 15 pixels on the right/bottom.

I have tried Googling & searching here for this problem, but can't find an explanation as to why runtime is different from the designer.

I should note I am using Visual 2010, and I am using a simple  for the layout.

Anyway, thanks for any clues as to why I am getting 15 extra pixels.

(Note I'd post a screenshot, but as a new user I'm not allowed).

Comment: Post a link to your screenshot, someone will edit your post to replace the link with the picture it's pointing to. Also you should post the XAML markup for your window, could be helpful :)

Comment: Thanks retailcoder. I actually started a brand new window and re-drew in the designer and it displayed correctly on the new window.

I compared the differences and here is what I found: if I set the width/height via the "Layout" category in the "Properties" window, the Window displays those extra 15 pixels.

With the new Window, instead of specifying a Width/Height in properties, I just clicked & dragged the border in the designer. In the XAML code it set 'd:DesignHeight="value" d:DesignWidth="value".

Not sure why the results are different, but now it displays correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to diagnose this.  It should allow you to inspect the entire visual tree of your application, and determine which UIElement is responsible for the extra pixels.